# What is the name of javaw.swing bundle in eclipse plugins folder

Tags: swing, osgi

I try to run OSGi application as a standalone application but it fails because it can not find the javax.swing bundle.

Comment: `javax.swing` is not a bundle. Please post the actual error message. Without this we can only guess what might be going wrong.

Comment: If you mean the package javax.swing, you might simply need to ad that Import-Package header to the MANIFEST. The tricky thing is that if you run from Eclipse/PDE it won't give an error, it will resolve anything in the JRE, but you really need to import anything outside the java.* packages

Answer (score 0):

OSGi is typically used for web-based "thin" clients.

Java Swing is exclusively used for desktop-based "thick" clients.

Q: Is your UI intended to run in a web browser?  Are you sure you need Java Swing at all?

If so, please do this:

1) Look at these links:

- http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/dynamic-swing-osgi-demo
- [How to create Swing OSGi bundles on AWT EventQueue with Spring DM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561161/how-to-create-swing-osgi-bundles-on-awt-eventqueue-with-spring-dm)

2) Please post:

a) the exact error message you're getting

b) Your Java version

c) You Eclipse version (if applicable; otherwise give us some information about your build environment)